# Changing an anchor property on "click" of another anchor item

Tags: html, css

It is possible to change the initial anchor property of one text item when another anchored property text item is clicked without using javascript?

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
<div class=links>
<ul>
<li>

<a href="#"onclick="MM_showHideLayers('what_we_do','','show');MM_showHideLayers('our_mission','','hide');MM_showHideLayers('who_we_are','','hide')" **class="active"**>WHAT WE DO</a> | 
</li>
<li>

<a href="#" onclick="MM_showHideLayers('who_we_are','','hide');MM_showHideLayers('our_mission','','show');MM_showHideLayers('what_we_do','','hide')" class>OUR MISSION</a> | 
</li>
<li>

<a href="#" onclick="MM_showHideLayers('our_mission','','hide');MM_showHideLayers('who_we_are','','show');MM_showHideLayers('what_we_do','','hide')" class>WHO WE ARE</a>

</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I would like to change the **class="active"** property in the first string to my default "a" assigned property when either of the other text links are clicked by the user and stay that way until it is clicked again.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you want to use JavaScript? How else would you do it?

Comment: you could make them a group of radio buttons, style them to look like the links, and then use the checked property instead of an active class.

Comment: Yeah j08691 - as I stated - I am wondering if there is a way to to do it with CSS. I seem to have issues with using javascript and it frustrates me because I have not learned the ins-outs of it yet.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need to use javascript/jQuery it's not tricky

First give all links the same class for example `btn`

```
<a href="#" class="active btn" >WHAT WE DO</a> | 
<a href="#" class="btn" >OUR MISSION</a> | 
<a href="#" class="btn" >WHO WE ARE</a>
```

Now add the jQuery:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
     $('.btn').removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

This script removes the active class from all the anchors and then adds it to whichever anchor has been clicked.

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok so I tried this and it's not working for me. I am very green when it comes to javascript and jQuery.

Comment: I changed the code as suggested to class="active btn" and class="btn" and jQuery as: 
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.btn').click(function(){
     $('.btn').removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
});
</script>

Comment: have you included a link to jQuery in your HTML abover your script? i.e. <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>